# How to declare flexible variable for workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to somehow declare dynamic workbook variables so that I can change workbook file names without causing errors.  My original thought was to use `Set Variable = ActiveWorkbook`, but that appears to give some peculiar errors:

```
    Set WkBk1 = ActiveWorkbook

    MsgBox (WkBk1.Name)
    WkBk1.Worksheets(1).Select
```

The above code works fine by itself. Afterwards, in the same procedure, I open a new workbook and run the following:

```
    Set WkBk2 = ActiveWorkbook

    MsgBox (WkBk2.Name)
    WkBk2.Worksheets(1).Select
    WkBk1.Worksheets(1).Select
```

I get an error at the last line, "Run-time error 1004; select method of worksheet class failed".  Can any one explain the source of this issue?  I'm guessing that it has something to do with using ActiveWorkbook to declare variables, or a faulty method of going between workbooks.

I should mention that the opened file is a .dat file opened in excel.

Ultimately, I want to have code that will assign two worksheets, of whatever file name, to their own respective variables.  I then want to copy and paste data between the two workbooks.

The actual code is below. The problem is with the copy statement in the for loop.
"Run-time error '438' object doesnt support this property or method".  Ive used similar syntax before and can't figure out why it isn't working here.

```
Sub Import3()
    ' Imports TSS samples from backlog

    Dim TSS As Workbook, Backlog As Workbook
    Dim Sample As Range, SearchRange As Range
    Dim Count As Long

    Set TSS = ActiveWorkbook

    ChDir ("C:\lwuser6")
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\lwuser6\BACKLOG.DAT", Origin:=437, _
           StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(7, _
           1), Array(68, 1), Array(78, 1), Array(86, 1), Array(126, 1), Array(150, 1)), _
           TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        ' for some reason _ has to be in between "Array(7, _1)"
            ' Can't be between list elements of encompassing list "Array"
    Set Backlog = ActiveWorkbook

    Set SearchRange = Backlog.Worksheets("BACKLOG").Range(Cells(1, 1), _
        Cells(Rows.End(xlDown).Row, 1))
    Count = 14

    For Each Sample In SearchRange
        Backlog.Range(Sample(1, 1), Sample(1, 3)).Copy
        TSS.Range("G" & Count).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Count = Count + 2
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It may not what you have been looking for, but [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  As a new user, I've been getting further and further away from using Select, but I still use it sometimes for debugging.  The above lines with select are actually not in my code, I just figured that they might demonstrate the root of the issue.  That said, I'm curious if there is a better way other than .select or .activate to bring the user to a specific workbook/worksheet.  I will definitely check out that link.

Comment: Note: instead of `Set WkBk2 = ActiveWorkbook`, use `Set WkBk2 = Workbooks.Open(yourpath)`....

Comment: I think you have to select/activate the workbook and then the sheet. You can't select a sheet on a non-active workbook.

Comment: @BigBen - Would I need to specify the file name for `Workbooks.Open(path)` ?  That is what I am trying to avoid.  @SJR I get an error when I attempt to activate or select the workbook by itself.

Comment: Actually I think you need `Activate` not `Select`. (But would re-iterate BigBen's point not to use either.)

Comment: *I've been getting further and further away from using Select, but I still use it sometimes for debugging* - your go-to debugger tool and new best friend is the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would warmly recommend running your code through [Rubberduck inspections](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/List) (it's free & open-source; I manage the project), since it explains not only the specific error you're asking about, but can also prevent you from stepping into a lot of common beginner traps.

The problem is that `Backlog` is a `Workbook` object, and `Workbook` doesn't have a `Range` member:

[image: "Member not found" inspection result]

> **Member not found**
>
> *A member access call is made against an extended interface that Rubberduck couldn't resolve, or the member couldn't be found. If VBA cannot resolve the type at run-time, error 438 will be raised. [...]*

You need a `Worksheet` to access a `Range`, a `Workbook` won't work.

Note that the subsequent `TSS.Range` call is just as illegal ;-)

---

<s>Take this:</s>

> ```
> Set Backlog = ActiveWorkbook
> ```

And get rid of the reliance on the side-effect of opening a workbook, by capturing the `Workbook` object returned by `Workbooks.Open`:

```
Set Backlog = Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:="C:\lwuser6\BACKLOG.DAT", Origin:=437, _
       StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(7, _
       1), Array(68, 1), Array(78, 1), Array(86, 1), Array(126, 1), Array(150, 1)), _
       TrailingMinusNumbers:=True)
```

*Nevermind, `Workbooks.OpenText` doesn't return a `Workbook` object reference.*

Then take this:

> ```
>  Backlog.Worksheets("BACKLOG")
> ```

And pull it into a local variable:

```
Dim backlogSheet As Worksheet
Set backlogSheet = Backlog.Worksheets("BACKLOG")
```

Now you can use it everywhere you need that particular sheet:

```
With backlogSheet
    Set SearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.End(xlDown).Row, 1))
End With
```

..and this should work, although IMO supplying `Range` objects to the `Worksheet.Range` property feels somewhat wrong (and will raise error 1004 if the `Sample` range isn't on the `backlogSheet`):

```
backlogSheet.Range(Sample(1, 1), Sample(1, 3)).Copy
```

Not sure which specific sheet in the `TSS` workbook you mean to paste things, but the same principle applies. That said, you probably don't even need to get the clipboard involved:

```
tssSheet.Range("G" & count & ":I" & count).Value = _
    backlogSheet.Range(Sample(1, 1), Sample(1, 3)).Value
```

Comment: Doh!!!!  I should have known better than to try and run a range without a worksheet.  I think it will help to be consistent with designating variables to  worksheets instead of workbooks, as you have shown.

For some reason, I get a compile error "expected function or variable" when just running the variable declarations and `Set Backlog = Workbooks.opentext` line.  Regardless, its all really good stuff, and I'm excited to integrate it.  I will check out the Rubberduck resource as well.  Thanks!